# Sending double to ASP.net MVC controler with AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have a problem with AJAX controler in ASP.net MVC. I have an app sending geo coordinates with AJAX to ASP.net MVC controler. These coordinates are double, but when I send them as a double, controler returns error page. But when I send coordinates as an integer, controler returns right result.

ERROR:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'latitude' of non-nullable type...
```

This works:

```
function()
    {
        $.post(url, 
               { 
                    "latitude"  : 28, 
                    "longitude" : 64,
                    "distance"  : 100
               },
               function(data)
               {
                    ...
               }
            );
    }
```

This not:

```
function()
    {
        $.post(url, 
               { 
                    "latitude"  : 28.457, 
                    "longitude" : 64.574,
                    "distance"  : 100
               },
               function(data)
               {
                    ...
               }
            );
    }
```

Controler:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetPlaces(float latitude, float longitude, float distance)
    {
        /* data mining */
        return Json(jsonPlaces.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: i'm happy to solve issue, i hope it worked for you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think it's a localization issue so you need to change values to comma seperated or you need declare local on mvc application

here is the dot to comma change code

```
var lati = 2.24;
var latitude = lati.replace (/\./g, ',');
```

please try it maybe it will solve

Answer (score 1):

Which data type are you using in your controller?
I've done something very similar like you are trying and it did work. I was using the .net **decimal** data type. Moreover make sure you are using really the same variable names (case-sensitive)

This is the ASP.net MVC controller code that worked for me:

```
public ActionResult SaveColumn(string ID, decimal Value, string comment)
{
  //...
}
```

That is how I called it in JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({ url: "SaveColumn?ID=" + id + "&Value="+val+"&comment="+comment, cache: false, success: function (data, textStat, jqXHR) { ... }});
```

Comment: Thank's, I've tried decimal type too, with same bad effect as double. I'll try use GET method and sending data in URL.

Answer (score 0):

If had this problem just this evening with DateTime. Turned out to be a localization issue. I suspect your's is too. For example, serverside is expecting 5.5 but receives 5,5 from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it is a localization problem, this works:

```
$.post(url, 
               { 
                    "latitude"  : "49,81", 
                    "longitude" : "12,44",
                    "distance"  : distance
               },
               function(data)
               {
                    ...
               }
            );
```

Is there any option how to disable localization formats on specified controller methods (especially for parametrs) but still use them in views?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem you had by using Globalization in Web.config.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx